# Помогите избавиться от повторений в if в PHP/Perl

Tags: php, perl, if, оформление

Есть большой if, нужно избавится от повторений и более грамотно и красиво оформить условие, но совсем не понимаю как это сделать.

```
    if ($contr_type == 0) {
        if ($contr_doc_id != 4) {
            if ($contr_doc_id == 1 && ($contr_ser_doc =~ /\D/g || $contr_num_doc =~ /\D/g)) {
                if (!$contr_bday) {
                    $personal_data = '1. паспорт и дата рождения';
                } else {
                    $personal_data = '2. паспорт';
                }
            } else {
                if ($contr_ser_doc && $contr_num_doc && $contr_bday) {
                    $personal_data = 'Ок';
                } elsif ((!$contr_ser_doc || !$contr_num_doc) && !$contr_bday) {
                    $personal_data = '1. паспорт и дата рождения';
                } elsif ((!$contr_ser_doc || !$contr_num_doc) && $contr_bday) {
                    $personal_data = '2. паспорт';
                } elsif (($contr_ser_doc && $contr_num_doc) && !$contr_bday) {
                    $personal_data = '3. дата рождения';
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (($contr_ser_doc || $contr_num_doc) && $contr_bday) {
                $personal_data = 'ОК';
            } elsif (!$contr_ser_doc && !$contr_num_doc && !$contr_bday) {
                $personal_data = '1. паспорт и дата рождения';
            } elsif ((!$contr_ser_doc && !$contr_num_doc) && $contr_bday) {
                $personal_data = '2. паспорт';
            } elsif (($contr_ser_doc || $contr_num_doc) && !$contr_bday) {
                $personal_data = '3. дата рождения';
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: ``subroutines`` - если перл. про пых не знаю.

Comment: А поподробнее ?

Comment: А что у вас в `$contr_doc_id`, `$contr_ser_doc`, `$contr_num_doc`, `$contr_bday` находится?

Comment: $contr_doc_id - число, 
$contr_ser_doc- строка, 
$contr_num_doc - строка, 
$contr_bday - строка

Comment: если еще конкретнее, то серия, номер документа и дата рождения. В contr_doc_id просто id-шник

Comment: если у вас эти большие `else` блоки одинаковы, то дополните условие с проверкой `!=4` сразу условием из вложенного if-а. Вообще, конечно, не читаемая хрень

Comment: напишите лучше, что тут вообще  происходит, и что вы хотите проверить и как.

Comment: А "1, 2, 3" в начале строк точно нужны ? зачем они ? Если бы из не было, можно было бы отдельно проверять паспорт, записав в переменную "паспорт". А после этого опять же отдельно проверить в одном месте дату рождения и дописать к переменной "И" в случае если она не пуста и фразу "дата рождения"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно отмечать отдельными битами отсутствие того или иного признака, а потом по их совокупности подготовить нужную фразу. Как нибудь так:

```
my $data=0;
if ($contr_type == 0) {
        if($contr_doc_id == 1) {
                $data=1 if($contr_ser_doc =~ /\D/g || $contr_num_doc =~ /\D/g);
        } else {
                $data=1 if(!$contr_ser_doc || !$contr_num_doc);
        }
} else {
        $data=1 if(!$contr_ser_doc && !$contr_num_doc);
}
$data |= 2 if(!$contr_bday);

$personal_data = {
        0 => 'Ok',
        1 => '2. паспорт',
        2 => '3. дата рождения',
        3 => '1. паспорт и дата рождения'
}->{$data};
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Все прекрасно работает, и выглядит в разы лучше)